# Qt: opening qrc pdf with the poppler library

Tags: qt, poppler

I'm having a bit of trouble with my function for displaying pdf's with the poppler library. The code below is the function in which the problem occurs.

const QString &file is the path to the file
int page is the page on which it has to open

When i set file to a real path (e.g. "/Users/User/Documents/xxx.pdf"), it is no problem to open it. But when i give the path to a qrc file (":/files/xxx.pdf"), it won't work. I want to use it for displaying a user manual for instance, within the application.

I've also tried first making a QFile out of it, opening it and doing readAll, then loading the QByteArray received by doing`Poppler::Document::loadFromData(the qbytearray)`, but it errors already when opening the QFile in ReadOnly mode.

```
void class::setPdf(const QString &file, int page)
{
    Poppler::Document *doc = Poppler::Document::load(file);
    if (!doc) {
        QMessageBox msgbox(QMessageBox::Critical, tr("Open Error"), tr("Please check preferences: cannot open:\n") + file,
                         QMessageBox::Ok, this);
        msgbox.exec();
    }
    else{ /*Code for displaying the pdf, which works fine*/
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me,

greetings,

Matt

Comment: How had you opened it with QFile? Normally, QFile reads resources from qrc in readOnly mode without any troubles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also tried first making a QFile
>   out of it, opening it and doing
>   readAll, then loading the QByteArray
>   received by
>   doingPoppler::Document::loadFromData(the
>   qbytearray), but it errors already
>   when opening the QFile in ReadOnly
>   mode.

```
QFile f;
f.setFileName(":/skin/AppIcon16.png");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray r=f.readAll();
```

Perfectly reads all data from the resource, have checked it. So i suggest you did something wrong when tried that. Maybe path errors, maybe something else...

Comment: does that error comes from QFile or from Poppler::Document::loadFromData(the qbytearray)?

Comment: qfile,

when i check it with if(!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"), f.errorString());
    }

it gives output that it might be corrupted(continuing), but when i load the same pdf, but then the real path on my HD, it works fine.
could it be that there is a difference with pdf and png in qrc files?

Comment: i don't think so. rcc just packs all what you put inside. So maybe you should regen your rcc file. Are you able to get other resources from that file?

Comment: yes, i have also a .ini file from which i retrieve page number, qDebugged it and it gave correct results. also deleted build-desktop folder and recompiled the whole thing, triple checked the path i provide, but still...

Comment: hmmm... that is strange. I don't know then what happens with your pdf... I still think that something is wrong with paths, but where...

Comment: ok, i have new info, it appears that the error doesnt come from qfile, but from poppler::document, i get: "Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)" 
"Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table..." 
"Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary" 
"Error: Couldn't read xref table"

Comment: I'm using the qrc "wizard" from QtCreator, when i make a new qrc file, it saves a qrc to the project folder, never seen an rcc file

Comment: try to save QByteArray you got from resources on disk and compare it for differences with the original file. If they are the same, than it's poppler's bug...

Comment: how do i do that exactly? I've never worked with qbyteArrays, do I write it to a file again?

Comment: i've done    QFile f2;
    f2.setFileName("/Users/Matthias/Desktop/bla.a");
    f2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    f2.write(r);
    f2.close();

but when i open the file with TextEdit, it gives nothing, also its 0 bytes

Comment: it seems that the QByteArray is empty.
qDebug(QString::number(r.size()).toAscii()); returns 0

Comment: and a qdebug of file.size gives 46, is there something wrong with f.readall then?

Comment: Ok, i feel stupid ... 1 uppercase letter should have been a lowercase one... Thanks for your time anyway, gotten to understand the resource files more thanks to you :-) I'm sorry to have waisted your time

Comment: yes, qt resources are case-sensitive... you may accept my answer and|or upvote it as a compensation for my time:)